# using awk to cut a specific part

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

i am dealing many lines containing paths
example :

```
posterita/posterita/web/jsp/pos/posReport1.jsp
build/web/view.jsp
uPortal-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/user-manager/selectUserAction.jsp
config/auth.php
database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php
admin/modules/announcement/functions.inc.php
```

what i need to do using bash print the first directory
I want the output to be like

```
posterita
build
uPortal-webapp
config
database
admin
```

the same method with second and third directory

```
posterita
web
src
seeds
modules
```

How can i use awk , sed or cut to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'/' -v n=1 'NF>n{print $n}' file
posterita
build
uPortal-webapp
config
database
admin

$ awk -F'/' -v n=2 'NF>n{print $n}' file
posterita
web
src
seeds
modules
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '/' {print $1;}
```

Change `$1` to `$2` to print the 2nd piece, etc.

The `-F` flag allows you to choose the delimiting character(s).

Comment: Just changing $1 to $2 won't produce the desired output for printing the 2nd directory. Note what happens to the `config/auth.php` input line.